# Is a function stored in memory only once?

Tags: javascript, function

Does javascript function stored in memory once when we define a function anywhere weather its in object or global.

```
function (){
alert("some value");
}

obj = {
 m: function(){
   alert('some value');
   }
}
```

Comment: Note that as shown, the first construct is a syntax error (a function declaration with no name). Only function *expressions* can be anonymous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you define the function one time, and pass a reference of that function to different variables/properties, then yes, it's stored one time.

```
var one_func = function () { console.log("I'm just one function."); };
var reused = one_func;
var reuser = { func : reused };
```

All of them have pointers to the same function.

But if you have something like this:

```
var Circle = function (r) {
    var circle = {
        radius : r,
        calculate_area : function () { return 2 * Math.PI * r; }
    };
    return circle;
};

var circle_1 = Circle(2),
    circle_2 = Circle(4);
```

The two objects do NOT share `calculate_area`.
You've created two distinct versions of the function.

And they must remain distinct due to function-scope and closures.
See, each copy knows about its own circle's `r`.

If you notice, I'm not looking at circle.radius, I'm looking at the `r` passed into the `Circle` function.

So any function which is defined ***inside*** of `Circle` has to be new every single time, because those functions save references to any variables inside of the constructor, through *closure*.

The memory-hit of having multiple copies, versus the benefits of having totally private properties is well worth it, until you hit thousands and thousands of copies (unless we're talking about gigantic objects or horrible old browsers, or running JavaScript on an LED screen on a Toaster).

More advanced engines might optimize the memory-footprint here, but it's rarely worth wasting the CPU, given how little memory each of these functions would take up, and how much RAM smartphones have (let alone custom-built gaming PCs).

---

**EDIT**
*for the sake of pedantry*

```
var Wallet = function (opening_balance) {
    var balance   = opening_balance,
        overdraft = 50,

        is_sufficient_funds = function (amount) {
            return balance + overdraft >= amount;
        },

        deposit = function (funds) {
            if (amount <= 0) { return; }
            balance += funds;
        },

        withdraw = function (amount) {
            if (amount <= 0) { return; }
            if (is_sufficient_funds(amount)) {
                balance -= amount;
                return amount;
            }
        },

        public_interface = {
            deposit : deposit,
            withdraw : withdraw
        };

    return public_interface;
};
```

Now, it should be blisteringly-apparent that we do not want `balance` or `overdraft` to be publicly accessible in any instance of `Wallet`.

Even this pedestrian version of Wallet is quite safe.

Sure, it's not doing any authorization right now, so you can deduct everything, or add a million dollars...

...but can you set your overdraft to $300?

Can you manually copy the value of `balance`?

Even if you created `var wallet = Wallet(35);` and then tried to rewrite the `deposit` method, your rewriting of it would then have absolutely no access to the private `balance`.

Now the closure-related benefits of this memory-overhead should be apparent.

If you'd prefer, you could consider the rate of fire of a gun in a multiplayer game.
Or a character's movement.
Or their health.
Or high-scores.

By keeping all of these things encapsulated in closures, they're untweakable.
That doesn't mean that the server is unhackable.
But it does mean that there's one less spot for people to get in, without rewriting your engine from the ground up.

Comment: There are JavaScript toasters? Where can I get one?

Comment: As soon as I find out, I'll tell you where I'm getting my toast, for the rest of my life.

Comment: ok then whats the need for the radius property when its not used any where.

Comment: It could be used in plenty of places...  ...you could use it in circumference.  You could use it in collision-detection, with other circles on a 2D plane, or against Axis-Aligned Bounding Boxes, or use it in Canvas measurements.  ...the point is that you can build all kinds of complex structures inside of a "constructor" function.  What you return to the outside world is publicly-accessible, and what you don't return to the outside world is inaccessible by anything at all *EXCEPT* by functions defined within the constructing function. The difference between `r` and `circle.radius` is pedantry.

Comment: between i love stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of hard to tell what you're asking, but I see two possible questions and therefore two answers:

1. A JavaScript function is created once for each execution of the execution context in which you've defined it. So if that context is global (outside of any function), yes, each declaration or expression will create only one function. If that context is within a function, they'll be defined each time the function is called.

   So for example, if this is a global scope:

   ```
   function foo() { }
   ```

   ...only *one* of those will be created. In contrast, something like this:

   ```
   function bar() {
       return {
           foo: function() { }
       };
   }
   ```

   ...creates a new function and assigns it to the `foo` property on the returned object *each time* `bar` is called. (That doesn't mean a smart JavaScript engine can't share the underlying code for them — and I'm told by people who claim to know that V8 [the engine in Chrome and elsewhere] does indeed reuse the code — but they'll be separate function *objects*.)
2. Each function declaration or expression creates its own function; if you have two equivalent declarations or expressions, they create *two* functions, even though they're equivalent. That doesn't mean that a smart JavaScript engine can't share the underlying code under-the-covers, but you'll still have two separate function objects.

   So for example:

   ```
   var a = function() { };
   var b = function() { };
   console.log(a === b); // "false"
   // Adding a property to `a`, since functions are objects, demonstrates
   // further that they are not the same function object
   a.foo = "bar";
   console.log(a.foo);   // "bar"
   console.log(b.foo);   // "undefined"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

No. The anonymous function

```
function(){
    alert("some value");
}
```

is **not** the same as the anonymous function inside the object literal `obj`.

To make sure you 'recycle' a stored object or function, do somethign like this:

```
var f = function(){ alert('test') };

obj = {
    m: f
}
```