# Is a function stored in memory once it is called?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I know there are many solutions with this type of question but somehow they are very complex.

I wanted to know what happens once a function is called. For example, in my sample code, when I call `keyboardHandler()` once, the eventHandler will add the `keyPressed()` and `keyReleased()` functions to the `keydown` and `keyup` events. But since they are not global functions (but defined inside another function), will I be able to access them outside, in the global area, when a key is pressed?

If yes, does that mean a function once called is somewhat stored in the memory?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var leftPressed = false;
var upPressed = false;
var rightPressed = false;
var downPressed = false;
function keyboardHandler() {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", keyPressed);
    document.addEventListener("keyup", keyReleased);
    function keyPressed(e) {
        switch(e.keyCode) {
            case 37: 
                leftPressed = true;
                break;
            case 38: 
                upPressed = true;
                break;
            case 39: 
                rightPressed = true;
                break;
            case 40: 
                downPressed = true;
                break;  
        }
    }
    function keyReleased(e) {
        switch(e.keyCode) {
            case 37: 
                leftPressed = false;
                break;
            case 38: 
                upPressed = false;
                break;
            case 39: 
                rightPressed = false;
                break;
            case 40: 
                downPressed = false;
                break;  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is called a closure.  its scope will be the function in which it is defined.  So no, it isn't global... and actually gets rebuilt (or at least re-pulled) every time time parent function gets called.  Since JavaScript runs so quickly, this is generally not a problem.  As far as it being in memory... yes, it will stay in memory until it gets garbage collected, but I don't think its memory residence is germane to anything.

Comment: So suppose I actually want to run this statement in global, `setInterval(function() {console.log(leftPressed)},1000);` and I know leftPressed will never be = true. So what do i do ? @JohnGreen

Comment: leftPressed is in the global context.  Because of that, if it gets modified, that modification is in the global context.  So, leftPressed *will* be true on keydown of keyCode 37.... of course, it will be released back up when you keyup...

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933290/is-a-function-stored-in-memory-only-once