# How to keep JavaScript function expressions in memory?

Tags: javascript

```
let sayBye = function () {
    console.log(`Bye`);
}

let bye = sayBye;   
sayBye = null;    // X

bye();            // Y
```

Before asking this  question, i searched in google and i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933290/is-a-function-stored-in-memory-only-once) post.

Then i thought, before line X the structure similar like this:

```
sayBye ---------------                                              
                      |      
                      |  => function() {....}
                      |
bye-------------------
```

After the x line, I thought it was like this:

```
sayBye                        MEMORY                                      
                            
                      |  => function() {....}
                      |
bye-------------------
```

But when i wrote bye in firefox developer tools i saw this

[image]

How is it possible? When i wrote `let bye = sayBye;` is the sayBye coppied?

```js
let sayBye = function () {
    console.log(`Bye`);
}

let bye = sayBye;   
sayBye = null;    // X

bye();            // Y

console.log(bye);
```

Comment: Chrome doesn't show this. Are you sure the snippet you shared is accurate? Can you confirm you didn't name your function, i.e. `function sayBye() {` instead of `function () {` on the first line?

Comment: You're currently creating a function *without* a name, and no `sayBye` is **not** copied, assignment `x = y` is not copying.

Comment: Oh wait, I just tried on Firefox, it does show that the function _seems_ named `sayBye` instead... That's odd!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name#Inferred_function_names:

> Variables and methods can infer the name of an anonymous function from its syntactic position (new in ECMAScript 2015).

Chrome and Firefox both give `"sayBye"` when printing `bye.name`.

---

From personal experiments, Chrome console shows `bye.toString()` when asking for `bye`, while Firefox shows a custom output of theirs, where they display the inferred name of the function (which makes sense indeed, as knowing the name usually helps debugging).

Answer (score 3):

Functions are object so assignment x = y is not copied  . I tried this Nodejs  I got

```
Bye
[Function: sayBye]
```

If you don't name a Function JS will automatically add name to  it.
In ES6 you can check name of function by using  *myFunction.name* ,i.e. 'name' is property of an function object .Important thing is that this is **read only** property.
Good practice is to use `const` instead of `let` while using function expression .Also ,if possible, try to name function debugging is easy on call stack

Comment: Although the `name` property isn't *writable*, it's *configurable*, so can be changed using `Object.defineProperty`...

Answer (score 2):

You are confused by the function's name.

The memory things happen exactly the same way as you thought.

However, the function didn't have an explicit name, so the browser gave an [implicit name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name#Inferred_function_names) to the function, that is the name of the variable or object property it was *first* assigned to, in this case, `sayBye`.

Then, it gets assigned to a different variable, but the name doesn't change.

You can see this if you give an explicit name to it:

```js
//  Explicit name ----vvvv
let sayBye = function myFn() {
    console.log(`Bye`);
}

let bye = sayBye;   
sayBye = null;    // X

bye();            // Y

console.log(bye);
```